# Nativescript tns assertion error

Tags: node.js, assertion, nativescript

When attempting to run any tns command I get the following error:

[image]

I'm running Windows 10 with node.js version 4.4.5.  It was previously working until I upgraded node.js from 4.4.0 to 4.4.5.  Any ideas?  I'm just working through the Groceries tutorial and have tried everything except for deleting the project and starting over from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to upgrade NativeScript tools and TNS modules 
following those instruction from the documentation: [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions). After you upgrade your modules you should delete `/node_modules` and `/platforms` folders from your project.